# Bind to nested object in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Having this component:

```
export class SearchPageComponent implements OnInit {
    results: Array<ResultsModel> = [];

    public constructor(private searchService: SearchPageService) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onSearch(new SearchCriteria());
    }

    public async onSearch($event: SearchCriteria): Promise<void> {
        this.results = await this.searchService.searchAsync($event);
    }
}
```

it's template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <results-list [itemsList.entries]="results"></results-list>
</div>
```

child component:

```
export class ResultsListComponent implements OnInit {
    public itemsList: ItemsList<ResultsModel> = new ItemsList<ResultsModel>();

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.itemsList.init();
    }
}
```

the `ItemsList` class:

```
export class ItemsList<T> {
    private resultsObserver = new BehaviorSubject<Array<T>>([]);

    @Input() public entries: T[] = [];

    public set items(value) { this.resultsObserver.next(value); };

    public init() {
        this.resultsObserver.subscribe(this.onResults.bind(this));
    }

    private onResults(entries: T[]): void {
        this.isLoading = false;

        entries.forEach(entry => this.entries.push(entry));
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how to pass data to `ItemsList.entries` property. I would rather keep something like this `[itemsList.entries]` syntax in the template, but is it even possible?

Using the above code gives me:

`Can't bind to 'itemsList.entries' since it isn't a known property of 'results-list'.`

I'm trying to achieve what can be expressed by what `[style.color]="whatever"` is doing. This works in ng2 I think, why won't my code work?

Comment: what is that you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to bind to properties of an object inside my component from it's parent :).

Comment: what do you  mean by this `I would rather keep something like this [itemsList.entries]`

Comment: Child component has this `itemsList` field - underlying class contains `entries` field, so by writing this sentence I meant that I would like to bind to it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively sure that the @Input properties only work on the child component, not on the type. So you would need this:

```
export class ResultsListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() itemsList: ItemsList<ResultsModel> = new ItemsList<ResultsModel>();
//...
}
```

And yes, you would then need to bind to itemsList and not itemsList.entires:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <results-list [itemsList]="results"></results-list>
</div>
```

But you could possibly do this:

```
export class ResultsListComponent implements OnInit {
    public itemsList: ItemsList<ResultsModel> = new ItemsList<ResultsModel>();
    @Input() public entries: T[];
    //...

    ngOnChanges(): void {
       this.itemsList = new ItemsList<ResultsModel>();
       this.itemsList.entries = entries;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but then Angular is giving me this error: `TypeError: this.itemsList.init is not a function`

Comment: As for your edit: yes, I was thinking about it, but I would rather have my ResultsListComponent totally stupid - not even knowing about this `entries` field. Besides, don't you think it's a bit silly, having entries in both - the component and the nested object?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of your project requirements to comment on that. All I can comment on is how the @Input property works. :-)

Comment: Apart from my project requirements - I'm marely trying to achieve what can be expressed by `[style.color]="whatever"` is doing. This works in ng2 I think.